# Where should I put the code to be automatically executed when .Net Core WebApi launched and make it recurring every week

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Excel file and want to extract the data into my Sqlite database. Ideally I want this function executed when lauching the project. But I have no idea how to structure the code. Should I invoke it in the `Program.cs` file?

Let's say the function is in a service class as follows:

```
public class DqcDataService : IDataSourceService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly DapperContext _context;

    public DqcDataService(IConfiguration configuration, DapperContext context)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
        this._context = context;
        List<DqcDto> dqcCodes = new List<DqcDto>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<DqcDto>> ReadFromExcelAsync(string filePath, string sheetName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The function `ReadFromExcelAsync` extracts data from Excel file and save into my database. I want this function gets invoked when launching the project. I have added the interface in the `Program.cs` file using `builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataSourceService, DataService>();`

How could I set my code structure to make it happen?

**Update 1:**

After @Pieterjan suggestion I have made some modification and I came into new issue. The whole **Startup.cs** file is as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Configure services here...
        services.AddControllers();
        //services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<IDataSourceService, DqcDataService>();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("IsDesigner", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Designer"));
            options.AddPolicy("IsChecker", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Checker"));
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        });
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Audience"),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:SecretKey")!))
                };
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        //Call your function during application startup
        try
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
                {
                    var dqcDataService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DqcDataService>();
                    await dqcDataService.ReadFromExcelAsync(@"C:\Users\ab\Management", "Points", CancellationToken.None);

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is after executing the line `var dqcDataService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DqcDataService>();`, the program stops executing the next line. Also it does not fire exceptions. The swagger page however gets refreshed. Somehow it finishes executing and waits for calling.

Could someone help figure out where I did wrong?

**Update 2:**

I found out that I made a mistake.
In the try block I changed to

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var dqcDataService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DqcDataService>();
    await dqcDataService.ReadFromExcelAsync(@"C:\Users\ab\Management", "Points", CancellationToken.None);
}
```

And then I got service not registered error. The same error happens even I changed `services.AddScoped<IDataSourceService, DqcDataService>();` to `services.AddTransient<IDataSourceService, DqcDataService>();`. In the end I got solved by changing into `services.AddTransient<DqcDataService>();`.

This confuses me more because `DqcDataService` class does implement `IDataSourceService` interface.

Now the issue is solved by it left me questions. Why removing the interface in `AddTransient` method successfully register the service?

**Update 3:**

Thanks for @Jalpa Panchal I have successfully enable the function to be executed by launching. Now I want to go further by enable the function to be executed once a week at certain time. I have tried to implement a  **RecurringTaskService**.

```
public class RecurringTaskService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private DqcDataService _dqcDataService;

    public RecurringTaskService(DqcDataService dqcDataService)
    {
        _dqcDataService = dqcDataService;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Calculate the time until the next Monday at 8 AM
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var nextMonday = now.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday - now.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7).Date.AddHours(8);
        var initialDelay = nextMonday - now;

        // Set the timer to trigger every 7 days after the initial delay
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, initialDelay, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private async void DoWork(object state)
    {
        await _dqcDataService.FillTableAsync(@"C:\Users\ab\Management", "Points", CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I register it using `services.AddHostedService<RecurringTaskService>();` but I then face error **System.AggregateException** saying

```
'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
 Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
 Services.RecurringTaskService':
 Unable to resolve service for type 'Services.DqcDataService' while attempting to activate 'Services.RecurringTaskService'.)'
```

I face the same error even I change `services.AddHostedService<RecurringTaskService>();` to `services.AddScoped<RecurringTaskService>();`

The solution I have is to copy the business code directly into the **DoWork** method in the **RecurringTaskService**.

Is there another way so that I do not need to have duplicated code and directly use the instance of DqcDataService?

Comment: I would probably create a `IHostedService` with no `while(true)` loop where you create a new scope (`serviceProvider.CreateScope`), resolve your service and run your commands

Comment: @Pieterjan I made the modification and face now a new issue. As updated in the question, I cannot get the line executed. Not aware where I did wrong.

Comment: I’d do this is a background service

Comment: You need to get your service by interface: `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDqcDataService>()` ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up)) The documentation is probably a good source of inspiration in this particular case

Comment: When you used `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DqcDataService>()`, you were specifically asking for a `DqcDataService` instance, not an implementation of the `IDataSourceService` interface. by registering the concrete class directly (`services.AddTransient<DqcDataService>();`), and then asking for it by that same concrete class type (`GetRequiredService<DqcDataService>()`), you aligned your registration and retrieval method, which solved the issue.

Comment: If you had registered the service using the interface (`services.AddScoped<IDataSourceService, DqcDataService>();`), then your retrieval should have been using the interface type like so:`var dqcDataService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataSourceService>();` This would have worked, assuming that the implementation (`DqcDataService`) would have been registered correctly with the `IDataSourceService` interface.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks for the help. I have successfully registered the service. Now I am facing another issue when I want to go further. I want to also launch the method once every week. As I have explained in the Update 3, I cannot use the DqcDataService in the newly created RecurringTaskService.

Comment: you could try this code in your DoWork` method to manually create scope:`private async void DoWork(object state)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var dqcDataService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataSourceService>();
        await dqcDataService.FillTableAsync(@"C:\Users\ab\Management", "Points", CancellationToken.None);
    }
}`